# Firebase server side OnDisconnect

Tags: java, firebase, server

I want to monitor firebase client connections from my java server.

I have found a lot of examples on how to use onDisconnect from the client side (iOS), and it works great.

But is it possible to monitor client connections from a java server using the java server sdk? I simply want my server to know about user disconnects, but without the client having to 'tell' the firebase database that it has connected/disconnected.

The reason for this is mostly security, and a wish to trust the client as little as possible to do important tasks. Ideally most of my data should be 'read only' from the client, except for some 'write only' request queues consumed by the java server.

From the firebase java server documentation: https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/serverreference/com/google/firebase/database/OnDisconnect

> The OnDisconnect class is used to manage operations that will be run
>   on the server when this client disconnects. It can be used to add or
>   remove data based on a client's connection status. It is very useful
>   in applications looking for 'presence' functionality.

It seems like what I want to do is possible and supported, but I'm having a hard time figuring out how to make my server monitor 100-1000 connections realtime.

Lets say I'm monitoring a database reference that I know clients are monitoring. In that case none of the options to 'remove on disconnect' or to 'set on disconnect' are useful.

Thanks a lot for reading this, I'm REALLY loving firebase right now, just a few more issues to figure out :-) Also sorry for my english, I'm not a native speaker.

Comment: Have you found a solution to this problem? I'm having a very similar issue.